# How to make the application responsive using Stack and Positoned - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to use **Stack** and **Positioned** to add a shape in the **SafeArea**, I tried to change the color of the AppBar and connect to the shape and add mediaQuery, but still not on every screen it will be properly connected. So how to get a svg photo on the entire surface of **SafeArea**, and to make it **responsive** without using appbar, is it necessary to get the effect like in the picture below?(the code gives the effect as in the picture, but it is not responsive and consists of two parts, and I would like one part and get responsive)

Any help very much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

```
class Shape extends StatelessWidget {
static Route route() {
return MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => Shape());
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0,
    actions: [],
  ),
  body: _profilePage(context),
);
}

Widget _profilePage(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: Align(
    child: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
            child: _curved(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

Widget _curved(BuildContext context) {
return SvgPicture.asset(
  'assets/images/shape_purple.svg',
  color:  Colors.blue,
  allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FitteBox Widget instead

```
FittedBox(
            child: Image.asset('assets/images/background.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            // decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //     color: Colors.white),
          ),
```

Comment: when I  use it it should cover SafeArea? and fit to every screen? so It ll be use as a AppBar?